# Get Account ID in PUBG API

Tags: pubg

I'm trying to get a PUBG player's details using the [Players developer API](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/players-endpoint.html).

I'm aware that both the operations of this Players API require the account ID of the respective player, whose account details are required.
However, I tried my best to find the account ID (starting with `account.` and having 32 alphanumeric characters), but all in vain.

In this aspect, I've two specific questions:

1. How can I find my PUBG account ID?
2. If I want to fetch other players' details via API, how do I get their account ID programmatically? Or should I need to ask for their account ID explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter[playerNames]=myPlayerName` as shown in the [player docs](https://documentation.pubg.com/en/players-endpoint.html#/Players)

On succes, it wil return a object containing the account_id;

```
https://api.pubg.com/shards/steam/players?filter[playerNames]=myPlayerName
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "player",
      "id": "account.c0e511111111111893af",
      ...
```

Replace `myPlayerName` with the username you're looking for.

---

<sub>edit;</sub>

[This Community Manager](https://forums.pubg.com/topic/181310-pubg-nickname-character-or-symbol/?do=findComment&comment=598260) says that only `-` and `_` are allowed in nicknames, url-escaping won't be necessary!

Comment: the `mPlayerName` that you're suggesting to provide, is it the player's username?  
If yes, then it doesn't work for those usernames which have any special symbol or characters.  Also, I'm aware of this solution, but it doesn't help my cause in any way unless the special character/symbol of usernames is recognized in the API.

Comment: Could you send me an example of a username? Did you try url-encoding/escaping/`'``'`?

Comment: @KnowledgeCraving Checking some [PUPG leaderboard rankings](https://pubg.op.gg/leaderboard/?platform=steam&mode=tpp&queue_size=1) I can't find any usernames with special chars in them. Are you sure thats even allowed by PUPG?